# Slow transfers on Debian

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi

I have esxi 6 (on an HP microserver) running with FreeNAS (raw assigned storage) and Debian as virtuals with jumbo frames enabled throughout (HP 1gb switch). When I copy files from my Windows machine (non esxi host) to FreeNAS (ESXi host), I get 90mb transfers. When I copy files to Debian (ESXi host), I get 15mb transfers if I'm lucky. Therefore I've narrowed it down to a Debian issue as I know the internal virtual ESXi network is running at 1gb/sec with jumbo frames enabled. I've tried copying files via Samba (15mb sec) and ftp (5mb sec); can't understand the slowness. Can anyone throw some light on the situation? I was sure I configured Debian with jumbo frames correctly, but maybe not. I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Which specific HP Microserver are you using, only one specific model is supported with ESXi 6/6u1 - the Gen 8 with the E3-1200v2.

Anyway your 'internal network' does NOT run at 1Gbps, it runs at CPU speed when two VMs are in the same port group, it only drops to actual line-speed during PG ingress/egress.

If I've understood your question and you can go from an external Windows server into your FreeNAS VM at 90MBps and yet when you go from the same Windows box into your Debian VM then the issue is highly likely to be a network configuration issue with the Debian VM. Presumably you've enabled Jumbo Frames on the vSwitch, the Windows server and any physical switches outside the ESXi host?

Comment: yes i have done that configuration.